# dataGridView CheckBox checked dosen't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a dataGridView that his first column is checkBox.

i want to use checked event on this checkBox.

this is my code:

```
  dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += (sender, e) =>
            {                                                          


                if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
                {

                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Control;
                    cb.CheckedChanged += (s, e1) =>
                        {
                          dosomething();
                         };
                    }
                };
```

but when i change the checkbox in the first column it never goes into the checkedChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your event to a [CellContentClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead, and then check if it's your checkbox column:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
     {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        if (cbCell.Value == cbCell.TrueValue)
        {
            cbCell.Value = cbCell.FalseValue;
        }
        else
        {
            cbCell.Value = cbCell.TrueValue;
        }
      }
}
```